# Can Vue's computed be nested?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I've seen a code similar to this and I'm wondering if it's a good practice or if it makes sense at all to nest the `computed` properties?

Example 1:

```
const a = computed(() => {
   const b = computed(...);

   // ...
})
```

Example 2:

```
// useMyComposable.ts

export const useMyComposable = () => {
   // ...

   return {
      a: computed(() => ...)
   }
}
```

I don't seem to find examples like this in the docs. In my understanding the *example 1* doesn't make sense because the nested `computed` properties would get recreated whenever the parent is reevaluated. Is this correct? Is this the case in the `example 2` as well?

I'm relatively new to Vue and I come from the React background, so I keep thinking of Vue's composables as React's hooks.

Comment: You can use the computed "a" function that as is in the second computed.
Everytime the "a" result is reevaluated, so will be the second one

Comment: Vue reactivity api == hooks, composables == custom hooks. They aren't always strictly limited to the use in the body of a component as in React but some are, they are used like that as a rule of thumb. 1 is wrong, 2 is ok.